# How to add custom message exit dialog to wix installer

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, action, wix3.6

I want to add message to `ExitDialog` in wix installer. how can i do that?

I need to add message like this - Please restart you machine to make changes.

I have tried something like this.

```
  <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="TFSServiceInstaller" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="MainExecutable" />
      <ComponentRef Id="TFSShortcut" />
    </Feature>

    <UI>
      <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="TARGETDIR" />
      <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Custom" />

      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />
      <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title"  FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

      <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />

      <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
      <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
      <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
      <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="2"></Publish>

    </UI>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
```

only display that message would be enough for me. ( no need of check box)

Comment: More details - http://tilr.blogspot.com/2013/09/create-wix-installer-for-windows.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for this need to add following property.

```
 <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="Please Restart your Computer." />
```

then it will add text to exit screen. for more details [see here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html)

Comment: Your question and answer greatly helped me, thanks s bunch!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the REBOOT Property of WIX to restart prompt in the Product.wxs file of your Setup. Syntax is :-

```
<Property Id="REBOOT" Value="Force"></Property>
```